# Getting Invalid Number Exception on elastic search query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am executing this query :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "studyID" : {
        "query" : 1,
        "type" : "boolean"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "25-34" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1992",
          "to" : "1983"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "84-*" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1933"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "18-24" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1999",
          "to" : "1993"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "75-84" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1942",
          "to" : "1933"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "0-17" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "2017",
          "to" : "2000"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "55-64" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1962",
          "to" : "1953"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "65-74" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1952",
          "to" : "1943"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "35-44" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1982",
          "to" : "1973"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "45-54" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "1972",
          "to" : "1963"
        } ],
        "format" : "yyyy"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "activityType" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "activityType"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where I just want to aggregation activity based on date ranges and then sub aggregate those ranges by activity type but Elastic search is giving me this exception :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
                "reason": "Invalid number format [yyyy#]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "study",
                "node": "MWkXAAOCSYuM-ubdkulNnw",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
                    "reason": "Invalid number format [yyyy#]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

Any Ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `format` parameter is to specify in which format the dates should be returned in the response, not in which format they are specified in the request. So depending on the date format of the `timestamp` field you have specified in your mapping type, your request needs to contain full-fledge dates, like this:

```
"25-34" : {
  "date_range" : {
    "field" : "timestamp",
    "ranges" : [ {
      "from" : "1992-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to" : "1983-12-31T23:59.59.999Z"
    } ],
    "format" : "yyyy"
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "activityType" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "activityType"
      }
    }
  }
},
```